# solace and message driven channel adapter

Tags: spring-integration, solace

Has anyone had experience using spring integration and Solace?
I am able to get Spring JMS working fine `(@Jmslistener(destination="testQueue"))` but when I try the same with a message driven channel adapter, I receive no message at all. Config:

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter channel="auditChannel"
                                        destination-name="testQueue"/>
```

and in the Endpoint

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "auditChannel")
```

the full service activator class

```
@MessageEndpoint("auditLogger")

public class AuditLogger {

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "auditChannel")    
    public void logMessage(Message message){
        System.out.println("============> " + message.getPayload());
    }
}
```

In Solace, I have created the 'testQueue' and able to send and receive using jmsTemplate.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You want to get message from jms to your Service? If so, you shoud edit (inputChannel = "auditChannel"), beacuase already you have two diffrent channels, without connection beetwen

Comment: Oh, that is correct. I have (inputChannel = "auditChannel"),

Comment: Ok, could you add to this question full service activator class? What you have in logs? You should try to enable  a DEBUG level for category org.springframework.integration in you log library.

Comment: Added service activator code.

Comment: The adapter uses the exact same technology underneath; it's likely a configuration problem. As has already been suggested, DEBUG logging should tell you what's happening.